# One of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ must be normal, for some prime $p $ dividing $|G|=870$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $870 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 29$. Show that at least one of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ must be normal, for some prime $p $ dividing $|G|$.

The number of Sylow $29$-subgroups is of the form $1 +29k$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and divides $30$. Thus the number of Sylow $29$-subgroups is  either $1$  or $30$. If there is only one Sylow $29$-subgroup, then we are done. Thus, let us assume that there are $30$ of them. Now, these Sylow $29$-subgroups have prime order, so they intersect trivially, and provide us with $30\cdot 28=840$ elements of order $29$.

Symilarly, there are at least $6$  Sylow $5$-subgroups (If we assume that it is not unique) and thus there are $6\cdot 4=24$ elements of order $5$ in $G$.

Repeating the same procedure, there are at least $10$  Sylow $3$-subgroups (If we assume that it is not unique) and thus there are $10\cdot 2=20$ elements of order $3$ in $G$.

Finally,  there are at least $3$  Sylow $2$-subgroups (If we assume that it is not unique) and thus there are $3\cdot 1=3$ elements of order $2$ in $G$.

So We have counted (adding the identity element) $840+ 24+20+3+1>870$  elements, wich is impossible. Thus at least one of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ must be unique and hence normal, for some prime $p $ dividing $|G|$.

Is what I have done correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: It's fine; you already have way too many elements so it's still a contradiction!

Comment: Yes, 100% correct!

Comment: Excellent! Now prove that the group must have a normal Sylow $29$-subgroup.

Comment: A hint for one way of solving Derek's exercise is to reuse [these arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463823/11619).