If $G$ is a group of order $29 \cdot 30$, then $G$ has a normal Sylow-$29$ subgroup
Write $|G| = 29 \cdot 30 = 29 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. Of course, I must show $n_{29}=1$. Toward a contradiction, suppose $n_{29} \neq 1$. Then $n_{29}=30$. Counting nonidentity elements, $G$ has $30(29-1) = 30 \cdot 28$ elements of order $29$.
Now, $n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3 \mid 29 \cdot 2 \cdot 5$ which means $n_3 = 1$. Counting nonidentity elements again, $G$ has $1\cdot(3-1) =2$ elements of order $3$. From our findings, we have
$$(30\cdot 29) - (30 \cdot 28) - 2 = 30(29-28)-2 = 30(1)-2= 28$$
remaining elements of order $1$, $2$ or $5$. For simplicity, let's work with the $27$ elements of order $2$ or $5$. Now, $n_2 \in \{1,3,5, 15,29, \dots\}$ and $n_5 \in \{1,6\}$. Now, since we only have $28$ elements left, counting elements, $n_2 <15$. So $n_2 \leq 5$. Now, if $n_5 =6$, then $G$ has $6 \cdot (5-1) = 24$ elements of order $5$ which means $G$ has $4$ elements of order $2$. But $4 = 4(2-1)$ and $4$ is not a choice for $n_2$. So $n_5=1$. But now $G$ has at most $2 \cdot 5 + 5 \cdot 1 = 15 < 28$ elements of order $2$ or $5$, a contradiction. Thus, $n_{29}=1$.
This method of counting elements is messier than any counting method I've encountered before which is why I have my doubts about it. But I see no issues with my methodology. Does this look okay?

Why did you skip $n_3=58$ case?

I've added the solution-verification tag because, well, that's what you're asking. Technically this means that you need to identify a specific step in your proof that's in doubt, but since this is so short and focused on a single technique, I personally think it's fine (other people might come to other conclusions, however).

Although I disagree with your full proof (why can't there be elements of composite order?), the general idea is good. The central idea is to show the elements not of order $29$ form a (normal) subgroup, and then show that's a contradiction. The Burnside transfer theorem makes this very easy, but is more advanced than just counting.

@SteveD I think he skipped it because it would mean having $58*(3-1)=116$ non-identity elements but we don't have that many because it has $840$ elements of order $129$ out of $870$ elements.

@SteveD He skipped $n_{3}=10$

Here's a suggestion that still uses counting: show that at least one of $n_2,n_3,n_5$ is $1$, then work in a quotient.

@Mahmoudalbahar ah, you're right. I did skip $n_3=10$. Well, without having control over that, the argument may become even messier yet! Surely, there must be some more efficient way to do this than count elements all day perhaps?

It's not that big problem because you can easily exclude $n_{3}=10$, because it would lead you  to having $20$ non-identity elements, so, with your first lines we have $840+20+1=861$ elements(I also count the identity now), so the remaining number of non-identity elements is $9$, but this contradicts possible values of $n_{2}, n_{5}$

@GrigorHakobyan In your final points, you have $27$ non-identity elements and this doesn't contradict having  $n_{2}=3$ and $n_{5}=6$, so you can't reach contradiction easily.

Related Question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4181373/870236
